# Loading snapshot dependency in Maven (3.3.5)

Tags: maven

I am using Maven Repository(local repo) to store my own generated artifacts.

Now in my project I want to add Snapshots version of dependency.

I have added this in my project pom.xml to specify repo.

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-artifactory</id>
            <url>http://172.16.3.179:8080/artifactory/libraries-test</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

This is my dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.b.c</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

SNAPHOST version is hosted at repo (with timestamp)

I am getting error

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project : Could not find artifact com.b.c:cache-lib:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in local-artifactory (http://172.16.3.179:8080/artifactory/libraries-test) -> [Help 1]
```

How should I resolve this?

I have updated the pom to

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-artifactory</id>
            <url>http://172.16.3.179:8080/artifactory/libraries-${enviornment}</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>local-snap-artifactory</id>
            <url>http://172.16.3.179:8080/artifactory/libraries-snapshots</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Now It is trying to fetch snapshot version from local-snap-repo but still same error,

Error log :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project location-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project : Could not find artifact com.b.c:cache-lib:jar:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT in local-snap-artifactory (http://172.16.3.179:8080/artifactory/libraries-snapshots) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: I have setup my own jfrog maven repo. In that I have local repo named libraries dev. Inside that I have hosted my snapshot version.

Comment: All paths are correct. Same is working when I am using normal version. Just snapshot version in not working

Comment: I have aleady aded this. please see the updated questions. Still wont work.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: No, they are not same . I dint update the error log. Now I have updated it

Comment: Now the artifact names are different. Please consider asking a cleaner question. With some debugging efforts made by you.

Comment: Artifacts name have version change. rest is same. this version is also updated at maven repo. Like i said, there are no issues with paths as without snapshot everything seems to be working fine